# Best way to configure poweroff keyboard shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

What's the best/right way to configure GNOME/Unity so that hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> will Power Off the system when no more windows are open? (pop up the Power-Off dialog).

(running Ubuntu 12.04.1)

Comment: You want to do it only when there are no windows open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.There is no short-cut for Power-off. But you could add one.

Go to System Settings ----> Keyboard -----> Click on the shortcuts tab ----> Click on the **+** button.

Now enter some name of the shortcut and the command `gnome-session-quit --power-off --force`.

Now you can apply whatever keyboard shortcut you want to it. Click on the word that says **Disabled**... when you click **New accelerator...** will be shown. Now you assign it to whatever keyboard shortcut you want to it (that is by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> when you see the word New accelerator...)

Comment: Well, that works, but it tells me "this shortcut is already in use and setting a new command would overwrite the current" (which is close-window for alt+f4)    ..   Is there a way to have it hierarchical, as in Xfce etc., so it only triggers the session-quit when no windows are opened? Else: Accepted answer!

Comment: I’m not sure if there is any way to have it hierarchical.

Comment: So there's no way to replicate behaviour of Xfce, Windows, et al. Well, thanks anyway --acepted as best answer.